# Word for the belief people are incapable of being selfless.

Tags: single-word-requests

It's not nihilistic, I just can't remember. It is when you hold the belief that no one does something unless they benefit from it. The belief people are incapable of being selfless.

Comment: Hi Lizzy, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cynical, I think, will do what you want.

It means 1. ‘believing that people are motivated by self-interest; distrustful of human sincerity or integrity.
"her cynical attitude"

2. concerned only with one's own interests and typically disregarding accepted or appropriate standards in order to achieve them.
   "a cynical manipulation of public opinion"

Answer (score 0):

If I won't do something unless I benefit from it, I am being [**selfish**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selfish):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : concerned excessively or exclusively with oneself : seeking or concentrating on one's own advantage, pleasure, or well-being without regard for others
> **2** : arising from concern with one's own welfare or advantage in disregard of others
> // a selfish act

---

However, the *philosophy* of this is called [**egoism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egoism):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1a** : a doctrine that individual self-interest is the actual motive of all conscious action

From the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/egoism/):

> In philosophy, egoism is the theory that one’s self is, or should be, the motivation and the goal of one’s own action. Egoism has two variants, descriptive or normative. The descriptive (or positive) variant conceives egoism as a *factual* description of human affairs. That is, people are motivated by their own interests and desires, and they cannot be described otherwise. The normative variant proposes that people should be so motivated, regardless of what presently motivates their behavior.

It goes on to mention **psychological egoism**, which is the specific term for what you describe:

> The descriptive egoist’s theory is called “[psychological egoism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/psychego/).” Psychological egoism describes human nature as being wholly self-centered and self-motivated. Examples of this explanation of human nature predate the formation of the theory, and, are found in writings such as that of British Victorian historian, Macaulay, and, in that of British Reformation political philosopher, [Thomas Hobbes](https://www.iep.utm.edu/hobmoral/).

---